# ¿Como agregar eventos a un listado de botones en un ciclo con Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

Buenas, tengo esto en mi código Jquery:

```js
    $("#borrarImagen0").click(function() {
      editarImagen(0);
    });

    $("#borrarImagen1").click(function() {
     editarImagen(1);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Quiero hacer algo como:

```js
for(i = 0; i < 2; i++) { 
  $("#borrarImagen"+i).click(function() {
    editarImagen(i);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Pero no esta funcionando, la verdad no entiendo bien el porque, porque es un bucle simple, pero aun así no funciona.

El problema es que tengo otro bucle de estos, pero donde son 15 elementos y si tengo que hacer alguna modificación es muy engorroso cambiarlo en todos lados.

Busque por todos lados, pero no encontré la manera de solucionarlo.

Comment: Hola Fedo, te recomiendo mirarte alguna guia y mirar los bucles. Espero que te sirva y suerte

  [1]: http://librosweb.es/libro/fundamentos_jquery/
  [2]: http://librosweb.es/libro/fundamentos_jquery/capitulo_2/bucles.html

Comment: Tienes la variable `i` declarada?

Comment: Y porque no te funciona?, yo no veo el error en ningún lugar

Comment: Fedo, que no funciona?. No se lanza el evento clic? Intenta poner un console.log(i) y verifica si se esta ejecutando.

Comment: La variable i esta definida, cuando hago i = 0 al principio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Otra opción con JQuery (y es6) es usar una clase de este modo

```
<button class="eliminar">Click</button>
```

Luego seleccionar y usar `each()` de jquery, de la siguiente manera :

```js
function editarImagen(imagenId) {
  alert('Editando ' + imagenId);
}

$('.eliminaImagen').each((index, element) => $(element).click(() => editarImagen(index)));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="eliminaImagen">Elimina 1</button>
<button class="eliminaImagen">Elimina 2</button>
<button class="eliminaImagen">Elimina 3</button>
<button class="eliminaImagen">Elimina 4</button>
```

Según las disposición de tus imágenes, quizá necesites corregir algunos indices.

Answer (score 2):

No sé cómo has declarado la variable `i` del bucle for, pero posiblemente el problema venga de ahí: el bucle itera sobre `i` desde 0 hasta 2. Cuando `i` vale dos, el bucle se para.

Entonces viene el posible problema: Cualquier click hace que se ejecute `editarImagen(i)`, pero `i` vale 2 para todos los elementos si se ha declarado como `var` o si es una `variable global` (no declarada):

```js
for (var i=0;i<4;i++) {
  $('#b'+i).click(function() {
    console.log('La variable i vale ' +i);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="b0">Click</button>
<button id="b1">Click</button>
<button id="b2">Click</button>
<button id="b3">Click</button>
```

Este problema se soluciona usando `let` para declarar la variable, porque para cada iteración se crea de nuevo y, por tanto, para cada llamada a la función `editarImagen`, tendrías una variable con valor distinto.

```js
for (let i=0;i<4;i++) {
  $('#b'+i).click(function() {
    console.log('La variable i vale ' +i);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="b0">Click</button>
<button id="b1">Click</button>
<button id="b2">Click</button>
<button id="b3">Click</button>
```

Comment: Invencible!, que genio!!!! me salvaste la vida, sos un grande!!! anda perfecto!

Answer (score 1):

En lugar de andar con for, usa `each` para asignar la funcion de clicar a todas las imagenes, y luego trabaja con ella con `this`. Te he colocado una funcion de borrar las imagenes tambien para que veas como funciona.

```js
$(document).ready(asignarfuncion);

function asignarfuncion(){
    $( "img" ).each(function(index) {
        $(this).unbind();
        $(this).click(function(){
            editarImagen(index);
        });
    });
}

function editarImagen(index){
    $("img").eq(index).remove();
    asignarfuncion();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://gloria-project.eu/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/logo-256-transp.png"/>
<hr/>
<img src="https://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/fallout/images/a/a0/Internet_Explorer_9_logo.png/revision/latest?cb=20110908011258&path-prefix=es"/>
```

Comment: El código no está del todo bien. editarImagen() agrega un listener adicional al resto de las imágenes cada vez que das click. puedes comprobar inspeccionando los elementos img en el navegador y ver 2 listeners después de dar click a una imagen :P

Comment: @ArieCwHat ya limpio el click ahora con el unbind. Si eso era lo de menos, la cosa es la idea de usar el each y el this.

Comment: @ArieCwHat de todas maneras, no se proque ami no me aparecen dos eventos en chrome... por eso no me habre dado cuenta. Pero tienes razon si.

Comment: Creo que tiene un botón actualizar el visor de eventos en chrome, es un poco absurdo que no lo haga en tiempo real :v

Comment: Es muy completo y agrega cosas que no estan buenas, fijate las otras 2 opciones que estan mas claras, a mi me re sirvio y espero que a vos tambien.

Comment: @FedoPeralta no es mas complejo, simplemente tiene la funcion de borrar tambien añadida, al final es muy parecida al resto. Con el mismo concepto que la respuesta aceptada de Arie, aunque efectivamente me gusta mas la otra, por hacerla un poco mas corta.

Comment: @GDP ok, pero a lo que voy es que para el caso, esta bueno ver algo mas simple y despues uno lo complejiza tanto como lo necesita.
Gracias por tu aporte.